# Calling an array, having it not only display each item but also their position within the array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Trying to come up with a way to assign a specific position to a item in an array based off of the number of items that are in the array. To give an example, if I had 10 chairs in a row in front of me, based off of the first person walking in I would assign them the first chair second person the second chair and so on (basically what an array does). However everytime I add in an item to the array I want that item (when the array is called) to display its position at the end.

```
array = ["item1 is in position 1", "item2 is in position 2"...]
```

Here is my idea so far. Btw it is designed to be a simple way give each item a number based off of their position in the array.

`def keeping_track(array)
   new_array = []
   array.each {|item| new_array << "#{item} is currently in position ____"}
   return new_array
 end`

The ____ area is where im lost at, im also kind of new to ruby. I would think there is a way to call the items location in the array, add 1 then convert that number back into an integer but im just not sure where to even get started with that. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `each_with_index`

```
 array.each_with_index {|item, position| new_array << "#{item} is currently in position #{position}"}
```

This will number the positions from 0, if you want to show the first position as position 1 then you can do `#{position + 1}`

Comment: If OP wants the first position as 1 then `each.with_index(1)` is also an option.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @SagarPandya Reallly?  What version did that get introduced?

Comment: `Enumerator#with_index` has been around a while, since 1.9.1 at least.

Answer (score 2):

This could be another approach, using map.

```
def keeping_track(array)

  array.each_index.map {|item| "#{array[item]} is currently in position #{item + 1}"}

end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may wish to check out [this guide on how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), if you haven't already.